# Multi-row labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization

I have a plot which contains multiple entries of the same items along the x-axis.  I have a total of 45 items grouped according to the groups below.

```
  pvalall$Group<-c(rep("Physical",5*162),rep("Perinatal",11*162),rep("Developmental",3*162),
                   rep("Lifestyle-Life Events",5*162),rep("Parental-Family",13*162),rep("School",3*162),
                   rep("Neighborhood",5*162))
pvalall$Group <- factor(pvalall$Group,
                        levels = c("Physical", "Perinatal", "Developmental", 
                                     "Lifestyle-Life Events", "Parental-Family",
                                    "School","Neighborhood"))
```

[image]

So essentially there are 162*45=7290 points along the x-axis and each 162 set of them corresponds to one of the variables of interest.  How do I get geom_point to only plot one lable for each of these 162 given a list of the variable names `c("var1","var2",....,"var45")`?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example ?

Comment: Sorry I posted this at the end of the day right bfore I wne tot bed.  I should have put more effort into it

Comment: Is the answer I provided acceptable?

Comment: No sorry I think you may have misunderstood.  I ended up using the scale_x_continuous and then providing breaks midway through each 162 set of points

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/scale_x_continuous\

Answer (score 1):

A reprex would be nice, but generally the solution is to create a separate dataframe with one row per group indicating where the labels should go, and to add a `geom_text()` layer to your plot that uses this dataframe.

My guess is that the code should look like this:

```
# create a dataframe for the labels
pvalall %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarize(Domains = mean(Domains),
            `-log10(P-Values)` = mean(`-log10(P-Values)`)) -> label_df

# now make the plot 
pvalall %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Domains, y = `-log10(P-Values)`)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = Group)) +  # putting col aesthetic in here so that the labels are not colored
  geom_text(data =label_df, aes(label = Group))
```

Here is an example with `mtcars`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(mpg = mean(mpg),
            disp = mean(disp)) %>% 
  mutate(cyl_label = str_c(cyl, "\ncylinders")) -> label_df

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(cyl)), show.legend = F) + 
  geom_text(data = label_df, aes(label = cyl_label))
```

produces
[image]